# power apps problem with sharepoint person or group field

Tags: powerapps, sharepoint-list, powerapps-canvas, powerapps-formula, powerapps-selected-items

I hope you can help me, what happens is that I have a sharepoint gallery, where I have several fields, one of them is Person or Group type, when I bring the information to the gallery I have no problem and it appears well even in a form that I have to view and modify works. The problem is that I need to create an html file and then a pdf but when I put it as a label it marks an error but if I put it to bring a different type of data if it accepts it.
attach an example of the html that I am using and with these fields if it brings me the user's data, but the name gives me an error[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p8Lvx.png)
Thanks for the support

Answer (score 0):

Did not understand you question completely but assuming you want to use the person or group value to other places like in PDF or HTML.

You can first store the value in a variable and use it where ever you want. For let's say you are showing people and group value on a textinputfield1 then use this example - `UpdateContext({PeopleValue: textinputfield1.Text)`  or you can check if you want the people picker value for a specific row in gallery using **IsSelected**

Answer (score 0):

People picket field will always be in Combo Box because it is a record type value. If you want to store the name in your HTML.
try this let's say your combo box name where you choose people picker value is ComboBox1
then on your label's text property write: ComboBox1.Selected.DisplayName.
This will store the name of that person in label.

Answer (score 0):

Person Group type is an array. You must loop throught the array or use an agregate function.

```
Concat(Table, Field, Separator)
Concat(ThisRecord.User, DisplayName, ",")
```